# Spring Integration. Unknown host and tcp-connection-factory

Tags: spring, tcp, lazy-evaluation, host, spring-integration

I'm implementing the TCP client using the Spring Integration. 
The requirements are:
 1. Through the UDP connection (from somewhere) receive the ip or host address of the TCP server.
 2. Open TCP connection to the server, to the destination host from previous step and  send some business data to this server.

I use the Spring Integration framework, version "2.2.0.RELEASE", and the problem is that in the default configuration of the **tcp-connection-factory** the **host** attribute should be "hardcoded" in xml. For example:

```
<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client" type="client" host="localhost" port="1234" single-use="true"/>
```

The question is how to avoid the *static* definition of the destination host in application context, and be able to 'lazy' initialise the tcp-connection-factory when the destination host will be known.

I know that this flow could be easily implemented by the standard Network APIs of Java, and the question is specific about the Spring-Integration API

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the configuration is static.

You could however use a similar technique to that used in the [dynamic ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) which configures ftp outbound adapters at runtime.

Comment: Also the current version in the 2.2.x stream is 2.2.6, please don't use such an old release.

Comment: yes you're absolutely right, but not always it possible due to restrictions of the 'enterprise' organisations. Anyway, in my case it is already updated to the latest :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as `<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory>` provides some instance of `AbstractConnectionFactory`. And from other side `<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter>` applies that instance via `connection-factory`, so, there is no stops to implement your own `RoutingConnectionFactory`.

The implementation may rely on some value from `ThreadLocal`. The idea is here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.java,

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.java

Comment: Thanks for tip. The only problem I see right now with this approach, that I have to use reflection in order to re-init the fields **host** and **port** in AbstractConnectionFactory, or reimplement the whole stack starting from interface ConnectionFactory. Both methods are bad IMO, and the current API assumes immutable state of those fields.

Comment: Actually, after some additional research I found that the implementation of the ConnectionFactory with additional 'dynamic' method for definition of the host and port works very well for my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: @jshark - I-m facting the same problem. Would you mind to share your solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible/easy - even if you customize or extend the class for tcp-connection-factory to be able to connect to changing hosts. There is an [open new feature request in JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3694) to provide this functionality.