# Spring integration - TCP connection client side - Host/Port obtained from message

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration, host

I know it is a similar problem to:
[Spring Integration. Unknown host and tcp-connection-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432929/spring-integration-unknown-host-and-tcp-connection-factory)

However, in my particular case the tcp-connection is established based on the si message flow. I am writing a program that "fakes" a user login to a particular site through tcp/ip connection. The host/port changes weekly so I prefer to dynamically set-up the connections. Hence, those host/ip for the destination server is not static.

I am still wondering whether there is any methods other than the [dynamic ftp sample] which set-up a whole new applicationContext for each tcp/ip connection and modifying the connection-factory which is non-trivial work.

My ideal case is:

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
request-channel="input"
reply-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"
connection-factory="client"
connection-host="#{headers.dest.host}"
connection-port="#{headers.dest.port}"
request-timeout="10000"
reply-timeout="10000"/>


<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
type="client"
host="#{headers.dest.host}"
port="#{headers.dest.port}"
single-use="true"
so-timeout="10000"/>
```

Where the destination host and port is inside the message header.

I know my use-case is rare but it's extremely useful in my particular business logic. My whole webapp runs based on the messages from those raw tcp-ip connections.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible/easy - even if you customize or extend the class for tcp-connection-factory to be able to connect to changing hosts. There is an [open new feature request in JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3694) to provide that functionality. [Simillar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768046/how-to-implement-a-tcp-connection-pool-in-spring-integration).